# Can Anyone reduce the Complexity of My Code. Problem E of Codeforces Round113 Div.2

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Link to The Problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/166/E

**Problem Statement:**

*You are given a tetrahedron. Let's mark its vertices with letters A, B, C, and D correspondingly.

An ant is standing in the vertex D of the tetrahedron. The ant is quite active and he wouldn't stay idle. At each moment of time, he makes a step from one vertex to another one along some edge of the tetrahedron. The ant just can't stand on one place.
You do not have to do much to solve the problem: your task is to count the number of ways in which the ant can go from the initial vertex D to itself in exactly n steps. In other words, you are asked to find out the number of different cyclic paths with the length of n from vertex D to itself. As the number can be quite large, you should print it modulo 1000000007 (10^9 + 7).*

**Input:**
The first line contains the only integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 107) — the required length of the cyclic path.

**Output:**
Print the only integer — the required number of ways modulo 1000000007 (10e9 + 7).

Example: Input n=2 , Output: 3
Input n=4,  Output: 21

**My Approach to Problem:**
I have written a recursive code that takes two input n and present index, then I am traveling and exploring all possible combinations.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define mod 10000000
#define ll long long   
ll count_moves=0;
ll count(ll n, int present)
{   
    if(n==0 and present==0) count_moves+=1, count_moves%=mod;  //base_condition
    else if(n>1){   //Generating All possible Combinations 
        count(n-1,(present+1)%4);
        count(n-1,(present+2)%4);
        count(n-1,(present+3)%4);
    }
    else if(n==1 and present) count(n-1,0);
}

int main()
{
    ll n;  cin>>n;
    if(n==1) { 
         cout<<"0";  return;   
    } 
    count(n,0);
    cout<<count_moves%mod;
}
```

But the problem is that I am getting Time Limit Error since Time Complexity of my Code is very high. Please Can anyone suggest me how can I optimize/Memoize my code to reduce its complexity?

#**Edit 1: ** Some People are commenting about macros and division well it's not an issue. The Range of n is 10^7 and complexity of my code is exponential so my actual doubt is how to decrease it to linear time. i,e O(n).

Comment: the code doesn't compile, where you are declering `mod`?

Comment: also your count function return value but you ignore it

Comment: As a micro-optimization, you can replace the `%4` with `&3`.  The `%` operation usually involves division, which is expensive.  You compiler may recognize the pattern and make the change, depending on the optimization level and the compiler's capabilities.

Comment: You definitely need to improve your typing skills so that you don't need to use abbreviation macros.  The macros actually make compilation longer (as it has to perform all these substitutions before compiling, versus parsing for know keywords).  The macros also make reading your code difficult.  We look at `ll` and then have figure out whether it's a type you created or a macro.  If you used `long long`, we would have no problems understand the declarations.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error, usually means that your implementation or algorithm is too slow and you need to seek out a faster algorithm.  Optimizing won't provide enough speed; use a different algorithm.

Comment: `if(n==0 and present==0) count_moves+=1, count_moves%=mod;  //base_condition` -- I'll be honest with you -- Can you explain why you are not simply using braces to enclose the `if` block?  The code is obfuscated enough with the macros, but this adds another level of obfuscation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you built into a recursion and you exceeded time complexity, you have to understand the recursion is likely the problem.

The best solution is to not use a recursion.

Look at the result you have:

2. 3
3. 6
4. 21
5. 60
6. 183
7. 546
8. 1641
9. 4920

⋮      ⋮

While it might be hard to find a pattern for the first couple terms, but it gets easier later on.

Each term is roughly 3 times larger than the last term, or more precisely,
[image]

Now you could just write a for loop for it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    count_moves = count_moves * 3 + std::pow(-1, i) * 3;
}
```

or to get rid of `pow()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    count_moves = count_moves * 3 + (i % 2 * 2 - 1) * -3;
}
```

Further more, you could even build that into a general term formula to get rid of the for loop:
[image]
or in code:

```
count_moves = (pow(3, n) + (n % 2 * 2 - 1) * -3) / 4;
```

However, you can't get rid of the `pow()` this time, or you will have to write a loop for that then.

Answer (score 2):

I believe one of your issues is that you are recalculating things.

Take for example n=4. count(3,x) is called 3 times for x in [0,3].

However if you made a std::map<int,int> you could save the value for (n,present) pairs and only calculate each value once.

This will take more space. The map will be 4*(n-1) big when you are done. That is still probably too large for 10^9?

Another thing you can do is multithread. Each call to count can instigate its own thread. You need to be careful then to be thread safe when changing the global count and the state of the std::map if you decide to use it.

Edit:
Calculate count(n,x) one time for n in [1,n-1] x in [0,3] then count[n,0] = a*count(n-1,1) +b*count(n-1,2) +c*count(n-1,3).

If you can figure out the pattern for what a,b,c are given n or maybe even the a,b,c for the n-1 case then you may be able to solve this problem easily.